# Detect checksum change of a file dynamically and trigger an api call

Tags: java, excel, spring, excel-formula

I need to trigger a job when there is a change in an excel sheet. Is there any elegant ways to detect the checksum change and to trigger an api call. I want to see is there a way to avoid periodical lookup for file change.